# pango_cairo_layout_path method does not respect kerning

Tags: gtk#, pango, kerning, pangocairo

I'm using pango library to do some text layout and cairo backend for rendering. It seems to me that the pango_cairo_layout_path method does not respect kerning.

I'm using c# bindings for pango and cairo that are provided with the gtk# project. Also i'm using the pango-cairo runtimes that also provided with gtk# project.

[Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcIO8.png) an image demonstrating the problem (Font: Arial)

First row is from Inkscape rendering and second row from pango-cairo

Is there any known bug in pango/cairo?... or i'm doing something wrong

Do you know any work around...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `pango-cairo` backend in Windows by default uses the `Win32` font type. With this type I had problems with kerning.

When I changed font type to be freetype everything worked as should.

In order to change font type please use:

```
PangoCairoFontMap * pango_cairo_font_map_new_for_font_type(cairo_font_type_t fonttype);
```

And

```
pango_cairo_font_map_set_default (PangoCairoFontMap *fontmap);
```

More info here: https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Cairo-Rendering.html